# Save Image ,from Library to Realm and present it in a different View controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm, uiimagepickercontroller

I have one View Controller that has three fields, UITextField, UIDatePicker and UIImageView.I select the image from the library and display it on myImage and this works fine.I think I have managed to encode the image into Data and I think I am saving it also, but when I try to choose an entry from my details View Controller tableview (decode the Data into an image and present it to my details View controller) I get this message "**Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**" ,next to my decompressImage function, what am I doing wrong?
Inside my didTapSave method I am trying to turn my image into data:

```
 let data = myImage.image
 let dataImage = data?.pngData()
 realm.add(newItem1)
 try! realm.commitWrite()
                
 //lastly I call the complitionHandler
    completionHandler1?()
```

lastly on the last VC I am trying to decode it into an image and present it:

```
func decompressImage() -> UIImage {
        let imageData = UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)
        let imageDec = UIImage(data: imageData!)
        return imageDec!
        }
    
    
    
//        //we need a formater to change our data into a UIImage
//        static let dataFormatter:
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //we assign
            itemLabel.text = asset?.titleNote
            dateLabel.text = Self.dateFormatter1.string(from: asset!.date)
            
            imagePresent.image = decompressImage()
        
}
```

Comment: I have added this piece of code in my imagePickerController method to turn my UImage into Data  "var dataImage = imageChosen?.pngData()" but how can I create an object of data and save it into realm, the same way that I do with date and text in my didTapSave function?

Comment: My initial problem was that I was trying to save an Image in Realm, but after reading the documentation, this is not valid , so I changed the entry ,in my class, into Data ,that is a valid entity.Then I turned my image into data(or so I think I did?) but I don't know how to use this data in order to save it into realm and how to retrieve and turn it into an image again in another VC.

Comment: You're adding more content and info in comments; please don't do that. Edit the question to include additional information please. Also, that's a LOT of code for us to parse through and because it's poorly formatted and hard to read the question is likely to be closed. Realm is not well suited for image storage so thats generally a bad idea, unless they are small - a thumbnail for example. Please use the formatting tools to properly format the code and shorten the length. Then we can take a look and see if we can help.

Comment: Two additional things 1) Please protect you're code by safely working with optionals `imageData!` is an issue as if it's nil, the code crashes (which is where the issue is - keep reading) 2) Most importantly, what are you expecting here `let imageData = UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)`? That's an empty image. The code in the `decompressImage` doesn't make any sense as it doesn't do anything (other than crash). Can you clarify what you're trying to do in general and also with that section of code?

Comment: @Jay  -Hi Jay, thank you for showing an interest on my query, what I am trying to do is choose a photo from the library and after displaying it in my EntryViewController , I want to transform the selected image into data and save it in Realm.

Comment: @Jay -The second part is when somebody is choosing the entry from the tableView, I want to retrieve the data, turn it into an image and display it on the NotesViewController. In here "let imageData = UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)" I am trying to add the data for the image chosen in the EntryViewController and decompress it, and now I can see that it is empty, but I don't know how to do it properly..

Comment: @Jay  -Do you have a suggestion on how to pull the data and decode them before presenting them on my last VC?

Comment: It would help to know where/what 'the library' is in this use case. If you have an image already, why do you need to decompress it or do anything other than display it? If you could clarify the question, we may be able to help.

Comment: @Jay  -Good morning , I pick the image from the photoLibrary of the device and on my entry VC I present it together with other information added by the user.I choose save and the data gets saved in Realm and my TableView gets updated with the entry. Upon clicking the cell we segue to a presentation VC where all the relevant information is presented in three fields.My Strings entered by the user are perfect but I can't present the image on my imageView.Do you think saving the image as a url path is better and then on the presentationVC referencing the address?is this possible?

Comment: A few things. Realm is not a good place to store images, especially if you're using Sync'ing. Something like Firebase Storage is a much better solution for images and then store the url to the image in Realm. Also for clarity you cannot *save the image as a url path* - you can save the url TO the image but the image is the image and the url path is a string defining where it's stored. Last thing; as mentioned previously. this code `let imageData = UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)` creates an empty image with no data so it's not clear what the plan is there.

Comment: @Jay  - Hi Jay, thank you again, I will investigate on how to do what you suggest above.With the solution that you propose , will the user be able to access the image if offline?Will there be a snapshot saved in the local device, so when the user is offline ,to be able to access it?And if not do you have another solution to suggest?What  I want to achieve is to keep a snapshot of the data on the local device for when the user is offline and then when online, to sync them with the online database.Is this possible?I believe that the code above is useless since I can't save the image as data.

Comment: @Jay -Is there a way to pull the dataImage form the entry VC and add it into the imageData constant in a different VC?This is what I am trying to create in this constant "let imageData = UIImage().jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)" but I don't know how to add the data of the image into it.

Comment: Wait. Let's be clear here. You CAN save an image as a NSData object but that's not what your code does. It defines an empty NSData object and doesn't do anything with it e.g. `return imageDec!` and the imageDec object is just an empty UIImage object. Storing images in the cloud protects your device from being overloaded - sure, you can store them locally but at what point do all of those images overload the device? 1000 pics, 100,000 pics? To answer the snapshot question - Firebase has offline persistence for data but not for images for the reason I just mentioned.

Comment: @Jay  -Morning Jay, the amount of images stored in the device using this functionality will be minimal(it's going to be a notepad for when something needs change or replacing).I want it in order to connect notes to an actual image when there is no internet access.Do you have a suggestion on how to save an image as a NSData object and how to make it do something in "return imageDec! "?I am going to concentrate on an online firebase course now, but first I want to sort out the above functionality for presentation purposes(I am a rookie, on my own ,trying to find answers).Thanks for your patience

Comment: StackOverflow is a great resource to help answer questions. Using the search at the top of the page if you type [swift]UIImage to NSData, you'll find a few dozen links that answer the question and code, examples and other similar questions. See [https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5DUIImage+to+NSData)